# Tags page: "Type to find tags..." text box

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

The [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) has a text box **Type to find tags**.  When I start typing, I get a list of available tags.  I've noticed a problem with certain tag names.  Take [googleearth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googleearth) (5 questions tagged) vs [google-earth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-earth) (12 questions tagged) for example.

When I start typing "google", I get a list of all google* tags.  However, entering "google earth" in the textbox gives me just one tag:  [googleearth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googleearth).

I think entering "google earth" in the textbox should return both [googleearth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googleearth) and [google-earth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-earth).  It seems like this is how it works when entering tags when I [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces aren't valid tag characters, and are simply ignored. When you type a character that doesn't exist in a tag it is truncated server-side.

```
google earth => googleearth
google!$%)earth => googleearth
google$%-e => google-e
google-earth => google-earth
```

**Update**
The behaviour you're describing is because tag search on ask a new question treats spaces as delimiters. So if you type `hello world` it will mark the first tag as `hello` and the suggestion drop-down will be possible matches for the word `world`. The word `hello` won't be considered at all in the search, as it appeared before the space. The error you describe is actually a misconception of how the tag search works.

Comment: Goto "Ask a new question" and type (without quotes) the tag "google earth" and see what the drop-down box offers:  both "googleearth" and "google-earth".  Why doesn't it do this on the Tags page?

Comment: That's not what happens.  Try it out.  I type "google earth", then select from the drop-down "google-earth" and my question is tagged "google google-earth".

Comment: Yes... that's exactly what I described... words before a space are not considered at all in the search.

Comment: D'oh! <smack's head> I see... "earth" is matching google-EARTH.  Sometimes I'm thick! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this topic: [The Great Tagging Reorg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg). It talks not abut ensuring that the myriad google*earth tags show up, but about consolidating tags under an accepted name.